# Filter Azure Application Insights requests by DNS

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have created an Application Insights resource in Azure and have it up and running.
I need to filter the data that is sent there so only data coming from a specific domain.
So, the application might be running in several places, like test and prod but I only want the logs from some of these domains.

What's the best implementation using Azure to filter all the possible requests from other domains that could "try" to send info there?

Answer (score 1):

Once it was already sent to AppInsights, you cannot remove it anymore. You can only filter it out in queries so that it is not shown, but it will be stored in the underlying datastore until the TTL expires.

If you do not want the data there, you need to filter it out on the sending side - or just not send it in the first place. So why don't you simply remove the instrumentation key from your non-prod environments?!

The better solution, however, would be to have separate AppInsights instances for each env.

Comment: My main concern here is that, if anybody gets the instrumentationKey, they would be able to send data to my instance. That's why I wanted to isolate at least some of the instances. It looks to me like a potential security issue

Comment: The instrumentation key is not considered a secret. I don’t know what kind of Site you will be running but if anybody really wanted, they can openly get the keys of really popular websites and send data there. The fact that this is not a real world problem should ease your fear 